# ServletContextListner still executing on removal from deployment descriptor and project directory

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans, servlet-listeners

I made a servletContextListener which was reading values from database and added it in the deployment descriptor. After testing I removed the servletContextListener file from project directory as well as from deployment descriptor and cleaned and build the project which happened successfully. But after this on running my application servletContextListener is executing and reading values from database. I don't know from where is this reading the values when the files is not present in the project directory.

I am running my application under Netbeans Apache Tomcat server.

Comment: cleaning tomcat work directory might help

Comment: @user2670177 sir my tomcat work directory contains nothing

Comment: There's no way that it could run, unless your war file or tomcat webapp contains some old code. Make sure all of them are well cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>your listener </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

remove this entry from web.xml

Comment: i have removed it from web.xml alraedy still problem persists

Comment: from netbeans remove deployed war in tomcat and then try

Comment: where can i find deployed war in netbeans tomcat ..i tried but did not get